# ZendService\LiveDocx returns zip file instead of docx

Tags: php, zend-framework, livedocx

I'm using the ZendService\LiveDocx library, but when I run this on our stage server (Linux) and request the format to be docx, it returns me back a zip file rather than the actual document.  The zip file consists of XML files describing the document.  If I request the format to be PDF it works fine. This works fine in my local development environment (Windows 7) when I try to generate a docx document.

Any ideas why the LiveDocx service would return a zip file instead of the actual document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The zip file consists of XML files describing the document.

That's how `.docx` files work.

A `.docx` in fact is a zip file, so you can simply rename them according to your needs.

You can try this by taking a "good looking" docx file and rename it to `.zip`, then extract.

The solution for your problem is to rename the file from `.zip` to `.docx` before exposing to the user as a download.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I've discovered in the interim that this is because of S3 and not Livedocx.  These are being stored on S3 with mime type application/zip.  I need to store these correctly in S3 with correct mime type.

Comment: @AdrianWalls Mime should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` I think.